# SQL Server 2016 : 233 error log entries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I tried to create `sa` user in SQL Sever 2016 but I can't log in and i am getting below error

> Connection to the server has been successfully installed , but then an error occurred at the entrance . (Provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - On both ends of the channel there are no processes .) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 233

All protocols are disabled except TCP/IP

I have enabled both Windows and SQL Server authentication. What can be the problem?

Comment: By the way I have already disabled all the protocols except tcp/ip. It didn't help...

Comment: You cannot create the "sa" user. You must add its password if  you've chosen Mixed authentication at installation. 
Btw, you can reset it with your Windows user.

Comment: You are connecting locally and have successfully connected using Windows integrated authN but failed to connect using SA. Did enable mixed mode authN during installation and set the SA password or did you enable mixed mode authN after the instance is up and running? If the latter, you need to set the SA password. As for your error 18456, see https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456

Answer (score 0):

The error states that SQLServer is not able to use TCP,IP for some reasons and tried using next protocol (shared memory) with out success..

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326280.aspx) states below as resolution..

> Use the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool to allow SQL Server to accept remote connections.

How to do that..

To configure the remote access option

> In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.
>       Click the Connections node.
>       Under Remote server connections, select or clear the Allow remote connections to this server check box

I also suggest using Port number in connection string.

Comment: I checked on the "Allow remote connections" button, but I still has the error - I can't connect to the server. The error number is: 18456

Comment: did you add portnumber at last,can you paste entire error and see if sql services are running from configuration manager

Comment: @SergeiK:you also can force tcp like this..tcp:server\instancename,portnumber

Comment: @SergeiK:are you trying to connect to sql locally or from remote

Comment: I am trying to connect SQL Server locally, I've just installed it on my comp. I can access it using windows verification, but I want to access it by sa. Where should I add the port number? Can you please show the example?

Comment: @SergeiK:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2495/identify-sql-server-tcp-ip-port-being-used/

Comment: Check if mixed connections is not enabled,and restart the services. See here: http://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/fix-login-failed-error-233/